# Why do you use relative clauses?

Tags: relative-clauses

now I am trying to study about relative clauses.
But I am curious about why do you use relative clauses?
For example, a thief is a person who steals thing.

also how do many English native speaker use relative clauses?

Comment: Even though I don't know about your first language, it would be a really big surprise for me if your first language had no relative clauses. I believe that you need to use it if you want to translate "a thief is a person who steals thing" literally.

Comment: @user1917217 Damkerng is just (helpfully!) pointing out that your language most likely has relative clauses, just like English.  Pretty much every language does.

Comment: "How many native speakers of English use relative clauses?"  **All of them.**  And they use them all the time―see [figure 1 here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2722756/) for a breakdown, with the Switchboard corpus representing conversation and the WSJ representing formal written English.

Comment: Because in the end, it's all relative. :P

Comment: I don't understand what does it mean " Even though I don't know about your first language, " Especially, what does mean the first language?

Comment: @user1917217 Your first language is your native language.  It was the first language you learned to speak.

Comment: Got it snailboat and I miss understood damkerng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use relative clauses to give additional information about the subject for which you are speaking. To take your example, let's take the basic sentence.

```
The thief is in jail.
```

We have a thief, and we have a jail that thief is in. Now, let's describe the thief using a relative clause.

```
The thief that stole my wallet is in jail.
```

Now the thief isn't just any old thief, the thief is **the** thief that stole your wallet, and that thief is in jail. The phrase *that stole my wallet* expands upon and shares its referent, the thief, with the the phrase *is in jail*.

And to answer your second question, native english speakers use relative clauses to flesh out the information given in a single sentence. Sometimes we go overboard with it too, and you'll get run on sentences like ***this*** monstrosity:

```
The car that my friend got from her sister which got scratched in the accident
last week with the bicycle in the crosswalk and ran into a tree is back from the 
auto shop.
```

So, to break it down:

- The CAR is back

  - The car was at an auto shop.
  - The car was received by my friend

    - The friend received it from her sister
  - The car was scratched

    - The scratch occurred in an accident
    - The accident occurred last week
    - The accident included a bicycle

      - The bicycle was in the crosswalk
    - The accident included running into a tree

Whew!

Comment: That monstrosity only has two relative clauses: *"The car [ **that** my friend got from her sister ] [ **which** got scratched in the accident last week with the bicycle in the crosswalk and ran into a tree ] is back from the auto shop."*